# How to get the maximum details from a remote host and forcefully get a particular IP?

Tags: ip, dhcp, mac

I have setup a Ubuntu server(xxx.222.4.216) for our Redmine tool and recently we got a IP conflict in the machine and now im unable to get back the IP(xxx.222.4.216). I would like to know if there is any possibility to forcefully down the IP from the LAN and get back the same.I will do the MAC binding once i get the IP address back.

So far i did the arp-a to get the physical address and the vendor look up too.Ethernet card is Asustek.I also tried to mstsc to the host and negotiation went through as well.So im pretty much certain that the remote host is a Windows7 based PC only.

Please let me know if there is any possibility to get the IP address back forcefully?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use dhcp [reservation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782789(v=ws.10).aspx) so that for this machine's mac address the ip xxx.222.4.216 can be saved.

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123746/how-to-request-a-specific-ip-address-from-dhcp-server) also might be helpful for you..

Comment: I would like to trace back to this particular machine.The hostname is some random name and I'm not able to narrow down to the host.Once the xxx.222.4.216 IP is down then i can Mac bind the IP to my Server's physical address

Comment: Did you try host or dig commands? host xxx.222.4.216 or dig xxx.222.4.216 or resolveip xxx.222.4.216 might be helpful for you..

Comment: If the address was given out by dhcp them your dhcp service's logs will probably contain the machine's network card's MAC. You then might be able to find clues using nmap or similar to scan for that MAC and if found looking at what is running on that interface.